# Approach to solving this set of equations with constant p?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

Does anybody have an approach to solve this by hand for variables $x,y,z,a$? Of course I could plug it into wolfram, but I wanted to know the fastest / smartest way to get it done by hand and would appreciate every help:

$yz+2ay+2az=0$

$xz+2xa+2za=0$

$xy+2ax+2ay=0$

$2xy+2yz+2xz-p=0$

with $p$ being a constant.

So far I have tried solving for and then replacing but it didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: a is a variable or constant?

Comment: a is a variable @AmerYR

Comment: @MJP: Maybe you can use the property $yz+2ay+2az=(y+2a)(z+2a)-4a^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around.

Multiply first by $x$,
second by $y$.

$xyz+2axy+2axz=0$

$xyz+2xya+2yza=0$

Subtract.

$2axz = 2yza$
so, if $az \ne 0$,
$x = y$.

Multiply third by $z$.

$xyz+2axz+2ayz=0$.

Subtract
$xyz+2xya+2yza=0$ 
to get
$2axz = 2xya$.
Therefore,
if $ax \ne 0$,
$y = z$.

Therefore
if $axy \ne 0$,
$x = y = z$.

The equations then become

$0
=x^2+4ax$

$0
=x^2+4ax$

$6x^2-p=0$

We have both
$a = -x/4$
and
$p = 6x^2
$.

Comment: How did you know to do that?

Comment: As I wrote, I just played around. I saw that I could get the first terms to agree as I wrote, and was pleasantly surprised to note that the second terms also agreed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @marty cohen: I guess im just not creative enough, i was going about this the wrong way. I was trying factor them all as $(y+2a)(z+2a)=4a^2...$ then multiply them to find $(y+2a)(z+2a)(x+2a)=8a^3$ but your way is much better... I wish i was as smart as you :)

Comment: I looked for things that were similar and tried to make part of them match. When a second part also matched, it became easy. Note that I have not handled $az = 0$ or $ax = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of solving the system which produces also solutions which are missing (while writing this answer) in the other answers.

This way is rather systematic and may be transferred to similar problems.

First $2$ observations:

- $3$ equations contain plenty of $a$ while the last one does not contain $a \Rightarrow$ It might be helpful to consider $a=0$ and $a\neq 0$ separately.
- All equations contain cyclicly replaced products of two variables. $\Rightarrow$ It might be helpful to consider differences of the equations to factor out $(x-y)$, $(y-z)$ etc.

Let's number the equations by $(1)$ through $(4)$ from top to bottom.

$\pmb{a=0}:$

We get $xy=yz=xz= 0 \stackrel{eq.\; (4)}{\Rightarrow}$ solutions can only exist for $\pmb{p=0}$ and are **not only** $\pmb{x=y=z=0}$, but also for $\pmb{t \in \mathbb{R}}$:

- $\pmb{x=t,y=0,z=0}$
- $\pmb{x=0,y=t,z=0}$
- $\pmb{x=0,y=0,z=t}$

$\pmb{a\neq0}:$

Let's consider the difference of the equations $(2)$ and $(1)$:
$$\stackrel{(2)-(1)}{\Longrightarrow}(z+2a)(x-y)=0$$

- Case $\pmb{z =-2a} \stackrel{into \;(2)}{\Longrightarrow}a=0$ **Contradiction** to $a \neq 0$. So, this is **not an option**.
- Case $\pmb{x=y} \stackrel{into \;(3)}{\Longrightarrow}x^2+4ax=0\Rightarrow x=0$ or $x=-4a$
- Subcase $\pmb{x=0}\stackrel{into \;(2)}{\Longrightarrow}2az=0 \stackrel{a \neq 0}{\Rightarrow}z =0 \Rightarrow$ solution only for $\pmb{p=0}$ is $\pmb{x=y=z=0}$.
- Subcase $\pmb{x=-4a}\stackrel{into \;(2)}{\Longrightarrow}-2az-8a^2=0 \stackrel{a \neq 0}{\Rightarrow}z =-4a \Rightarrow$ solution only for $\pmb{p=96a^2}$ is $\pmb{x=y=z=-4a}$.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the solution and the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring the first three equations...
$$yz+2ay+2az=(y+2a)(z+2a)-4a^2$$
$$xz+2ax+2az=(x+2a)(z+2a)-4a^2$$
$$yx+2ay+2ax=(y+2a)(x+2a)-4a^2$$
Now we can say
$(y+2a)(z+2a)=4a^2$ and so on. Because all three of the equations equal $4a^2$ we can say $x=y=z$.

Thus we can write...
$$(x+2a)^2=(y+2a)^2=(z+2a)^2=4a^2$$

Assuming $x=y=z\neq0$
$$(x+2a)=-2a$$

So, $x=y=z=-4a$

Comment: @trancelocation Ah yes the infamous $\pm$. I'm trying to be creative with my mathematical approaches, im really bad at coming up with out of the box solutions. Thanks.

Comment: You nicely show that it is a solution, but you don't show that it is the only solution.

Comment: @trancelocation: Is it ok now? If so please delete your comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30838/706407 Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: @martycohen: Does this fix the problem? I appreciate the help, nice solution btw

Comment: @Aops Vol. 2 : There are more solutions, actually.

Comment: @AopsVol.2 : (+1) for the approach. But, as i said: it is not complete. I have added an answer with a complete solution.